# Waterline associated field does not have the same type as referenced model pk

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, waterline, sqldatatypes

I was trying to create FK manually int a database created by Waterline but get blocked because of associated column does not have the same type as the pk.

> [Warning, Error code 150, SQLState HY000] Create table
>   'accounting_db/#sql-1c64_c' with foreign key constraint failed. There
>   is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns
>   appear as the first columns.

**Models**

```
  //Person
  {
    "identity" : "person",
    "tableName": "PERSON",
    attributes: {
       "id":{
          "type" : "integer",
          "primaryKey" : true,
          "autoIncrement" : true,
          "columnName" : "ID"
        },
        "name":{
           "type" : "string",
           "columnName : "NAME"
        }
    }
  }
  //Pet
  {
    "identity" : "pet",
    "tableName": "PET",
    attributes: {
       "id":{
          "type" : "integer",
          "primaryKey" : true,
          "autoIncrement" : true,
          "columnName" : "ID"
        },
        "name":{
           "type" : "string",
           "columnName : "NAME"
        },
        "person":{
           "model" : "person",
           "columnName : "PERSON_ID"
        }
    }
}
```

**CREATE TABLE queries for both models**

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `NAME` VARCHAR(255),
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
CREATE TABLE PET (
    `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `NAME` VARCHAR(255), 
    `PERSON_ID` INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

As you can see, column `ID` of table `PERSON` is `INT UNSIGNED` and the column `PERSON_ID` of `PET` has the type `INT`.
How can i treat this ? 
Thank you !

Comment: *How can I treat this?* - By changing the type of `PERSON_ID` to `INT UNSIGNED`.

Comment: Waterline is verbose!

Comment: It's rather obvious in SQL.  If it can't be done in Waterline, then write a serious bug against them.  Or abandon them.

Comment: @Binarus, i mean a solution via waterline

Comment: @RickJames, i think i should open an issue on github